# How do you defeat the first spider in Limbo?

Tags: limbo

How do you get past the spider in Limbo that is behind the tree trunk?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Run up to the spider, and just as its leg is about to do the stomp animation run back.  Do this a few times and a bear trap will fall from a tree branch to the left.  Push the bear trap to the spider and do the same thing you did before (wait for it to stomp and run away).  Position the bear trap so that it hits the bear trap.  Do this 3 times (against 3 legs) and you'll beat it.

Comment: Bara's got it right. Just remember that the third leg reacts rather quickly (far faster than the first two). I found out the hard way :/

Comment: Watch out for the third leg you snap in the bear trap - it goes faster than the other two and will get you if you don't back away early.

Comment: Also, something I found handy was to get on the opposite side of the trap from the spider and not let go of the trap. Just get him to swipe at you and take a step or two back when he's going to, keeping hold of the trap, rinse, repeat.

Answer (score 0):

A good guide to this boss can be found here: [How To: Beat Limbo’s spider boss](https://web.archive.org/web/20141207031607/http://www.2d-x.com/how-to-defeat-limbos-spider-boss/)

> 1. As you approach the spider boss, you’ll notice a bear trap resting on a tree branch. This is not an arbitrary move on Playdead Studios’
>      part; this bear trap is your key to victory. The hard part? Getting it
>      down.
> 2. Before the spider boss reveals itself a white butterfly will flutter away. This is not only acts as a warning that a world if hurt
>      is approaching, but showcases that objects in the environment react to
>      the spider boss’ presence.
> 3. You need to coax the spider boss to strike at you. This not very hard. What you need to do is have it strike and miss so that it’s leg
>      taps the ground. This may be hard.
> 4. Return to the tree. The bear trap will have fallen out of it. You have your weapon.
> 5. Push it toward the spider boss. Strategically place the bear trap on a place on the ground within the spider boss’ striking range. When
>      the spider boss rears its legs to strike, quickly drag the bear trap
>      to where it’s leg will hit the ground. The spider will strike the
>      trap, damaging itself.
> 6. Repeat until you claim victory. Or have you…?

Comment: oh look, a dead link